# Efficiently list all characters in a given Unicode category

Tags: python, unicode, character-properties

Often one wants to list all characters in a given Unicode category. For example:

- [List all Unicode whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921365/in-python-how-to-list-all-characters-matched-by-posix-extended-regex-space), [How can I get all whitespaces in UTF-8 in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245053/how-can-i-get-all-whitespaces-in-utf-8-in-python)
- [Characters with the property `Alphabetic`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843347/list-of-unicode-alphabetic-characters)

It is possible to produce this list by iterating over all Unicode code-points and testing for the desired category (Python 3):

```
[c for c in map(chr, range(0x110000)) if unicodedata.category(c) in ('Ll',)]
```

or using regexes,

```
re.findall(r'\s', ''.join(map(chr, range(0x110000))))
```

But these methods are slow. Is there a way to look up a list of characters in the category without having to iterate over all of them?

*Related question for Perl: [How do I get a list of all Unicode characters that have a given property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182420/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-unicode-characters-that-have-a-given-property)*

Comment: By the way, if you just want to *see* which characters are in which categories, I made a page with [**all** the characters](http://david.loyc.net/misc/CharCategories.html).

Answer (score 16):

If you need to do this often, it's easy enough to build yourself a re-usable map:

```
import sys
import unicodedata
from collections import defaultdict

unicode_category = defaultdict(list)
for c in map(chr, range(sys.maxunicode + 1)):
    unicode_category[unicodedata.category(c)].append(c)
```

And from there on out use that map to translate back to a series of characters for a given category:

```
alphabetic = unicode_category['Ll']
```

If this is too costly for start-up time, consider dumping that structure to a file; loading this mapping from a JSON file or other quick-to-parse-to-dict format should not be too painful.

Once you have the mapping, looking up a category is done in constant time of course.

Comment: @m.kocikowski: unless you are using Python 3, which the OP of the question clearly is (it'd fail in Python 2 otherwise).